# Assert.IsTrue(false) is passing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

Shouldn't `Assert.IsTrue(false)` throw an exception?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this doc: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Pass

Comment: @Vyrira thanks. should i delete the question since it's getting downvotes?

Comment: @User you can't delete questions that have an answer, and it seems neutral to me.

Comment: Also read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). "Assert.IsTrue(false) is passing" is not the problem. In more complicated code this XY problem can waste many hours. If `Assert.IsTrue()` was a very big complicated method then you'd be in there for hours wondering, "Why is this returning `true` instead of `false`", when it never had a chance to return in the first place as it was never called.

Comment: @Quantic I didn't know that it wasn't the problem when asking the question.

Comment: Just pointing out what stopped you from finding the problem yourself. Presumably you looked up what `Assert.IsTrue()` does, but something stopped you from looking up what `Assert.Pass()` does. "The test is passing after I assert a fail condition, why?" is the "actual" problem, "Assert.IsTrue(false) is passing" is entirely an assumption. If your car doesn't start you might think the starter is dead, but you should say, "The car doesn't start", not, "The starter is dead". If just the battery is dead there's no reason to even look at he starter. There's no reason to even look at `Assert.IsTrue`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Assert.Pass` throws `SuccessException`

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5

and that's why `Assert.IsTrue` *doesn't execute*

Comment: Correct. From NUnit's documentation: The Assert.Pass method allows you to immediately end the test, recording it as successful. Since it causes an exception to be thrown, it is more efficient to simply allow the test to return. However, Assert.Pass allows you to record a message in the test result and may also make the test easier to read in some situations. Additionally, like the other methods on this page, it can be invoked from a nested method call with the result of immediately terminating test execution.